# Unable to install anything on Windows 10

Tags: windows, permissions

I've recently reinstalled Windows 10 from scratch on an empty drive and proceeded to install some software when this error stopped me: ***"Windows cannot access the specified device, path, or file. You may not have the appropriate permissions to access the item."***

This has been driving me insane! The program I'm trying to install is Cheat Engine (downloaded from the official site. I'm using it on my OWN self-developed games to test how proof they're to it.).

I tried everything:

- Switched to the built-in Super Administrator account.
- Changed the file permissions from the security tab.
- Looked for the "Unblock" checkbox in the file's "General" tab.
- Created a new account from scratch with admin privileges.
- Added my account to the Administrators group using the lusrmgr.msc.
- I reinstalled Windows.
- Temporarily disable Windows Defender.

And the issue is getting worse! Now I can't even install Unity Hub, Can't install GIMP, Can't install HitFilm Pro, CAN'T INSTALL ANYTHING!

EDIT: As suggested by @harrymc here's my drive S.M.A.R.T. data:

[image: Drive S.M.A.R.T. Data]

Comment: Do you have the same Windows 10 license installed on another drive in the same computer? Try using just one drive and install Windows 10 on that. The built-in admin account will not likely help you

Comment: No, completely different, genuine Windows 10 Pro key from Microsoft's website.

Comment: And also, the new installation is on a completely different physical drive connected to a completely different motherboard.

Comment: Look in the Event Viewer for useful error messages and add them to your post.

Comment: @harrymc no errors at all in the event viewer (in all categories) for the past 24 hours.

Comment: Now check the SMART data of the system disk. If you want our help in analyzing it, add it to your post.